# Node.js port é escutada, porem nao abre no navegador

Tags: html, node.js, express.js, npm, back-end

Eu aplico o `npm dev run`, ele escuta a porta normal, porem qnd vou colocar o `localhost` e coloco a porta, o navegador fica somente carregando até dar a msg que não consegue conectar.

```
//Fazendo requisição e criando app
const express = require ('express');
const app = express();
const db = require('./db/connection');
//add porta
const PORT = 35 ;
//fazer escutar porta
app.listen(35,() => {
    console.log(`O express está escutando na porta`);
});

// db connection

db
.authenticate ()
.then(() => {
    console.log(`conectou com sucesso no banco de dados`)
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(`occorreu um erroo.`,err)
})
//ROTA

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    console.log(`Está Fumegando`)
});
```

Comment: Nessa rota `get` ai q você testa, o log aparece?

Comment: sim aparece toda vez que atualiza a pag.

Comment: E logo abaixo dele, pensou em adicionar um `res.send('Funcionou!');`?

Comment: CARA MUITO OBRIGADO, FUNCIONOU, TAVA DESDE ONTEM NESSA. VALEUU